# What hinge system can “hide” a drop down door?

Tags: hinges, hardware

I want to construct a tv console with a drop down door, but i want the door to fully retract into the cabinet after it’s dropped down. I’m not sure what type of hinges i need for that.
what hinge system can do that?

Comment: Some sort of drawing would probably help a lot since I can't envision a hinge that's also attached to a slider of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

[Series 123 Flipper Door Slide with hinges](https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/category/hinges-slides-and-opening-systems/slides-and-drawer-box-systems/slides/specialty-slides/pantry-slides/flipper-door-slides/series-123-flipper-door-slide-with-hinges/1008579?s=slide%20hinge)

[image]

Comment: As SE is a strict Q&A venue (i.e. not a threaded forum) Answers should not require clarification or a reply. The Comment system is for when we need clarification or to ask the OP a question such as this.

Comment: Thanks, answer was reworded

Answer (score 0):

Cabinet pocket door hardware, is the search term you want. (*Retractable door slide may also be helpful*)

[Accuride](https://youtu.be/lurm6mkAQfk) has several. The model [1316](https://www.accuride-europe.com/slides/1316)  may be the one you want as it appears to keep the door from swinging down when retracted.

Other models would work but you would need to ad a cleat on the sides of the cabinet to keep the door from swinging down when retracted. (*If used on top*)

These are all set up to be on top, (*or the side*) you state "drop down" I suppose you could use them in that orientation. The 1234 or the 1312 would work for that application.

Here is a [Accuride Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQl-Nwc6C5M) video showing all of those models.

There are many options, but this should point you in the right direction.